# Method Post with Axios giving Error 404. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

i have a problem with `axios.js`, i trying to use the method  `POST` but it give `error 404` and i dont know what do, the error is:

```
> POST http://localhost:3000/api/match 404 (Not Found)
> createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

My code with `post`:

```js
teste = () => {
  console.log('login clicked')
  let data = JSON.stringify({
    password: this.state.password,
    username: this.state.email
  })

  axios.post('api/match', data, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  })
}
```

Same thing if i to use this:

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/match', data, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
```

My `package.json`:

```js
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"
```

Someone know why be giving this error? ????
I look that it is giving the URL of the app React and not of the server..

Someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `api/match` to `/api/match` in your first `axios.post`. A possible reason your second post request with the full URL isn't working might be a `CORS` issue. There's a great [cors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) you can add to your backend app with two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The error says, basically, you don't have any http server running on localhost:3000 with a route /api/match.

Are the http server running?

Comment: I mean, is this the server address or , as you said, the React app address? 

if you type in your browser localhost:3000, does it displays a response from the http server?

Comment: Not, it is of the server, of the React app is 3000

Comment: You have to use this syntax:

`axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/match', data, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})`

and remove the `proxy` option from the package.json